# What is the correct way to refer to future that is spoken about in the past?

Tags: grammar, past-tense, future-tense, reported-speech

I want to talk about a moment in the future that I though about in the past. Is any of these sentences correct and why?

> I thought we might become more than just friends in the far future, when our friendship **would have become** stronger.
>
> I thought we might become more than just friends in the far future, when out friendship **would become** stronger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talking about a moment in the future where an event will have already come to pass. You are NOT talking about the moment in the future when the event happens. So "...would have become..." is correct. You can use either "...would have become..." or "...will have become...".

Comment: Thanks for your answer, 
Is there any difference between using "would" and "will"? 
Do they imply different meanings?
Shouldn't I use "would" because I used "thought" in the beginning of the sentence?

Comment: If you are sure that it WILL become stronger, use "will". If you are unsure but hopeful, use "would". "Will" is unconditional, "would" is conditional. You're expressing a chain of events that might happen, so "would" fits better.